# Ampersand is getting escaped

Tags: c#

I have an issue with my URL being stripped of the &ref=1 parameter and value. What's causing this?

Url is www.mysite.com/folder/category/5&ref=1

```
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(URLStr))
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["ReturnUrl"]))
        {
            URLStr = Request["ReturnURL"].ToString();
        }
```

**EDIT** My URL is Redirect.aspx?ReturnUrl=www.mysite.com/folder/category/5&ref=1

Comment: However you are generating your URL, it should be www.mysite.com/folder/category/5?ref=1 for the first parameter, any parameter after that would be preceeded by an ampersand such as www.mysite.com/folder/category/5?ref=1&param=2

Comment: After your edit. ReturnURL isn't stripped at all. ref=1 is another parameter for Redirect.aspx and has no relation to ReturnUrl.

Comment: @DanielB So how is it not showing up in the URL then?

Comment: @TCC `Request["ReturnURL"]` contains `www.mysite.com/folder/category/5` and `Request["ref"]` will contain `1`. In short ReturnURL and ref are two separate parameters that are given to the request of Redirect.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest starting your query string properly and see if that works:

```
www.mysite.com/folder/category/5?ref=1
                                ^ Changed & to ?
```

The`&` is used to denote additional parameters **after** the `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you are missing a QueryString separator on your URL.

Make your URL like this:

```
www.mysite.com/folder/category/5?&ref=1
```

And see what happens.